Why does each Block in the MSVC implementation of std::deque have only 16 bytes? Can I modify it?
I learned this fact after reading Inside STL: The deque, implementation, and I am very shocked by it. 16 bytes!? That’s only twice the size of a pointer! I know that the major implementations of the standard library is an array of pointers to Blocks, and since a Block is only twice the size of a pointer, why not just store the elements themselves directly (and implement it as a circular array)?
Based on my tests, an MSVC deque uses about 2.5 times more memory than a vector with the same capacity. Each 16-byte block is actually allocated 24 bytes due to memory alignment, plus around 8 bytes used for bookkeeping and an additional 8-byte pointer.
(Here, we temporarily do not consider the situation where larger elements are stored.)
I opened the <deque> header in my MSVC and found the Block's size:
// deque standard header in MSVC 2023 Community 17.9.7
    static constexpr size_t _Bytes = sizeof(value_type);

    static constexpr int _Block_size = _Bytes <= 1 ? 16
                                     : _Bytes <= 2 ? 8
                                     : _Bytes <= 4 ? 4
                                     : _Bytes <= 8 ? 2
                                                   : 1; // elements per block (a power of 2)

When the size of the elements stored in a deque is less than 16 bytes, each block in the deque only stores up to 16 bytes of data.
My question is, can I modify this part of the content in the deque standard header? For example, modify it to this:
    static constexpr int _Block_size = _Bytes <= 1 ? 64
                                     : _Bytes <= 2 ? 32
                                     : _Bytes <= 4 ? 16
                                     : _Bytes <= 8 ? 8
                                     : _Bytes <= 16 ? 4
                                     : _Bytes <= 32 ? 2
                                                    : 2; // elements per block (a power of 2)

What would be the impact of doing this? If I make these changes and save it as a separate deque_.h file, would I need to move it out of the std namespace (and modify the include guards)? Or, since I only modified the Block size, can I avoid introducing  and completely overwrite std::deque's _Block_size by placing #include "deque_.h" at the top and using the same include guards as <deque>?
By the way, since I increased the Block size, I also reduced the initial map size:
static constexpr int _Minimum_map_size = 4; // Originally 8

I just want to understand why the MSVC deque uses such a small block size and whether I can modify the block size by changing only a few lines of code without causing any issues. (Of course, I won't alter the contents of <deque>, I saved it as a separate header file.)
After making the modifications mentioned above, the memory usage for a deque with 10,000,000 elements, each 16 bytes, was reduced by half.
Edit:
So, why does each block in the MSVC implementation of std::deque have only 16 bytes? This decision was made decades ago, and no one knows the exact reason behind it now. Since changing the block size would cause an ABI break, Microsoft can't simply fix it. They missed the opportunity to address this in the last ABI update, even though simply increasing the block size to 64 bytes could have significantly improved memory efficiency.
Can I modify it? When might I be affected by an ABI break if I use the modified _Block_size? Is it when I pass a deque as a parameter to precompiled functions?

What would be the impact of doing this? -- The impact will be corrupting your installation of Visual C++.  Don't mess around with compiler header files -- if you have an issue, report it to the Visual C++ engineers.

Either don't use this container, or don't use MSVC STL (MinGW for the win).

You can't change std::deque implementation without compatibility issues including RTL. The question is what problem are you trying to solve? Are you trying to reduce the overhead? Are you thinking about improving locality, cache performance? Corner cases? Try making measurements, perhaps there is no problem to begin with.

Why...? Design decision from the 1990s.  Can I modify it?  Basically, no.  (Assuming you don't want to apply for a job at Microsoft working on the C++ compiler.  But if you do, then the answer becomes maybe.)

"why not just store the elements themselves directly?" Because that would be a vector. We already have that.  :-)

@BoP
vector cann't adding and removing items efficiently at the front.

use Boost.Container instead, it contains almost any kinds of containers you can imagine

@許恩嘉 - The deque can add elements at the front because it stores pointers to them (unlike the vector), and can therefore add a new block in front when needed. "You can't eat your cake and have it too."

@BoP
I know. But I have no cake. Where is the cake? Adding items efficiently at front? No, since when the map size needs to be increased, a large number of pointers have to be moved, since each block is very small. Efficient random access? No, it's slow in deque. Reasonable memory usage? No, due to small blocks, the MSVC deque uses over 2.5X memory of a vector. Standard library implementations should be efficient and use less memory, or at least achieve one of these goals or strike a balance between them. But the MSVC deque doesn't seem to meet these requirements. Why there is no cake?

or at least achieve one of these goals or strike a balance between them not all STL implementations are good. The MS STL was from decades ago, long before it was even open sourced, and nowadays probably no one can answer that except the members who wrote those code, even Raymond Chen already said he doesn't know why and probably it'll be the target in the next ABI break. They simple can't fix it now

ABI compatibility is the reason why many things in MS STL is bad, for example Why is valarray so slow?, or the wasteful SSO in std::string. Both GCC and MSVC have bad 32-bit std::string that can contain maximum 15 characters in SSO mode. Clang OTOH has 24-byte string that can store 22-character SSO strings, and you can even trade some performance to have 23-character SSO string if you write a similar string library. GCC also had a different std::string implementation until they can break the ABI. MSVC didn't do any ABI breaking yet

why not just store the elements themselves directly? The answer to this question is simple: the std::deque container can not store elements directly in the array because it would break Standard requirements on reference stability.
